# How can I automate an Excel file refresh and send via email?

Tags: excel

I have a few Excel files (Pivot Tables & Charts) that have a data connection to an Access database. What I'm hoping to do is have them automatically refresh and get emailed on the 1st of each month.

I do something similar in Access, where I have a database with a query that gets run and emailed. I accomplished this by creating a form in the database, having the form open automatically when the database is opened, and then used VBA within the form to run the query (DoCmd.OpenQuery) and then email it (DoCmd.SendObject)

Can I do something similar with an Excel file? I'm thinking I could set the Connection Properties under the Data tab to "Refresh data when opening the file", but that assumes the user has an active network connection as the database is on a server. Also, if the user saves the file and opens it again in the future, it will have current data and not the original data.

So in a nutshell I need to:

1. Open Excel File
2. Refresh Data
3. Email File

Comment: A macro can be written in a module which can be run at user's will. Regarding the issue about overwriting the original data, the macro will create a copy of the Excel file with the refreshed data and then mail that copy. But I have a question: If the user doesn't have active network then how would the user refresh?

Comment: `Also, if the user saves the file and opens it again in the future, it will have current data and not the original data.` Is this a problem or a request?? Do you want to send a COPY of the data in the worksheet to someone? Or the active worksheet with the active connection that will be refreshed, and also cause 1,001 security alarms to go off.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity .. I would like the user to receive a COPY of the data. The spreadsheet would need to be refreshed prior to being sent out, and then a static copy of that data sent to the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I ended up doing:

In Access, I have some Make Table queries that make tables (duh) which will be used by the Excel files. I created a form, have it open automatically when the database opens, and in the `Form_Load()` event I put the following:

```
With DoCmd
    .SetWarnings False
    .OpenQuery "My Query 1"
    .OpenQuery "My Query 2"
    .SetWarnings True
End With
Application.Quit
```

In each Excel file, I found some VBA code online to create a PDF and then email it. In the `Workbook_Open()` event, I have the following:

```
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
ActiveWorkbook.Connections("MyConnection").Refresh
ActiveSheet.Protect

Call FunctionThatCreatesPDFAndEmails

ActiveWorkbook.Close False
```

I then put some tasks in Windows Task Scheduler .. one to open the Access database (which causes the Make Table queries to run and then closes itself) and then one task for each Excel file that I need to update and email. So now I have Access updating the source data tables, and then Excel opening each file, refreshing the data, and emailing a PDF of itself. Mission Accomplished!