# Automatically Update/Sync Excel File saved on Different Computers

Tags: excel

I send off an excel file to different persons. Is there a way where in I can sync or automatically update the excel file they saved on their computers with the file I have? The file save on my computer will served as the original file/report and they will just refresh their copies. No need to send a new file everytime I will update the original copy.

Hope you could help me out of this.

Thanks.

Comment: Where are these other people?  Can you just upload the file to a shared location?

Comment: I've sent the file through email. We do not have shared location because these people are from different department. I am thinking if adding a "connection" in the excel will work to solve this.

Comment: What could you suggests? I will let them save the file I've sent and then just ask them to refresh the file.

Comment: google sheets is ideal for what you describe, at least for simple situations.

Comment: But not all the users have an internet connection.

Comment: If they don't have a connection then how could they refresh the information?

Comment: I've used the Connection feature under the DATA TAB of Microsoft Excel. I made two different excel file, 1. Original File where i could just update the records; 2. File where I will do the refresh. It works. This is just connected with the Original File. However, these two files are saved in my computer. My concern is that, how could I update the 2 files in case, the Second file is saved on different computers?

Comment: How would they do *anything* with your new data if there's no way to get it to them?

Comment: Is this a sort of hopeless case???

Comment: Would you help me out by using excel vba code or macros?

Comment: Try to follow this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15796433/how-can-i-automate-an-excel-file-refresh-and-send-via-email?rq=1                      
I think, we have the same concern. "Also, if the user saves the file and opens it again in the future, it will have current data and not the original data. "

Comment: Were you able to achieve this?